# GeneralSharePoint HowTo

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a general SharePoint question for the community. I would like to utilize our underutilized SharePoint intranet site by having building visitors log in and log out by filling out a form on a SharePoint web-page for which I would create using SharePoint Designer, In doing so I would eliminate the paper method at the security desk and I would be able to view the visitors in the building in real time and hopefully be able to extract data to Excel.

Please tell me if I am on the right path here

Comment: Sounds like a nice feature, but will this not require anonymous access on the intranet, so guests without AD account can check in?

Comment: Or the security folks at the front desk could utilize the form and sign the guests in and out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work in the way PirateEric hints to above.

Create a custom list with at least three fields: Visitor name, sign in time, sign out time. Other fields may include the visitor's company, who they are meeting on these premises and their mobile number.

Let the security guard add a new item to the list for every visitor. They enter the name and the sign in time (which can be a calculated default value).

The security guard saves the item and it will receive a SharePoint list ID. You could then have the security guard write that ID number on a visitor badge.

The visitor wears the badge while they are in the building and upon leaving check back with the security guard and hand in their visitor badge. The security guard brings up the visitor's log book item, either by name or by ID and enters the check-out time.

In busy rush-hour scenarios, visitors can just drop their numbered badges at the security desk into an "unattended exits" bucket and leave the building. Dropped badges can be processed whenever the staff find the time. The actual exit time may not be known (or the visitor may be asked to write the exit time on the badge before dropping it at the desk).

In an emergency situation, the SharePoint list shows all visitors that don't have an exit time and a quick check of the unattended exit bucket will show the badges that have been dropped but not yet been processed.

This is a very easy technical effort, a little bit of education for the security front desk, and a little bit of change management for check-in/check-out policy and procedure.

All in all a good example to go (almost) paperless (there's still the visitor badge) and have the data available not just for the front desk who keep the paper sign-in book, but also for the Health and Safety / Fire Wardens who need to tick off their lists in an evacuation scenario. No need to call the front desk for a copy of the paper book. Just pull the SharePoint view of visitors that have not yet exited.